# Angular with ngrx: local stores vs globals - dbsync

Tags: ngrx, angular

I have two questions relation the use of ngrx/store:

1. I have a big application, with different modules like customers, suppliers, etc, that are lazy loading.
   May I have a store by module or a global store?   It is possible to dinamically inject the local stores to the global where a module is called?
2. I understand the use of a local store.  But what is the good moment to update the server database.   That's why it's better to use ngrx/effects?

Thanks for you answers.
Marcos